# How can I hook up my own button to the downloadify lib

Tags: javascript

Does anyone know how can I hook up my own button to the downloadify lib
Instead of using

```
<div id="downloadify"></div>
```

I want to have this assigned to some other button or element. So I can avoid using the custom button it has.

The  the demo in the lib page is this one:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  Downloadify.create('downloadify',{
    filename: function(){
      return document.getElementById('filename').value;
    },
    data: function(){ 
      return document.getElementById('data').value;
    },
    onComplete: function(){ 
      alert('Your File Has Been Saved!'); 
    },
    onCancel: function(){ 
      alert('You have cancelled the saving of this file.');
    },
    onError: function(){ 
      alert('You must put something in the File Contents or there will be nothing to save!'); 
    },
    transparent: false,
    swf: 'media/downloadify.swf',
    downloadImage: 'images/download.png',
    width: 100,
    height: 30,
    transparent: true,
    append: false
  });
</script>
```

And can be found here:
http://pixelgraphics.us/downloadify/test.html

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just specify any id.

```
Downloadify.create( id_or_DOM_element, options );
```

Comment: You still have to use the image, or if you specify your own button is not clickable. Probably i just have to mask my dom element with my own image. But since i am using dojo i did not want to do that

Comment: Did it by creating transparent image and hooking it up to the dom element.

Answer (score 0):

Best solution is what "setlio" said
You set the buttons image as a transparent image and put the text or picture you want below it